# Can I choose my Roth IRA contribution belong to 2019 or 2020 made between 1/1/2020 and 7/15/2020?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, roth-ira, turbotax

I am trying to fill my tax return by TurboTax. I saw this:

> Enter your total Roth IRA contributions for 2019.
>
> Note: include contributions made between 1/1/2020 and 7/15/2020 that you want to include on your 2019 return.

The deadline filling tax return for this year is 7/15/2020. I made the contribution on 4/15/2020.

Does that "you want to" mean I have choice to decide which my contribution belongs to, either 2019 or 2020?

Because I over contributed in 2019, I hope to make it belong to 2020 so I don't need withdraw or pay the penalty.

Thanks!

Comment: Years ago I did this and I just wrote the account number and the tax year I wanted in the check's "Memo" field.

Comment: There was a similar question yesterday: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/127664/can-i-still-contribute-to-a-roth-ira

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The choice of 2019 or 2020 is made when you made the contribution, not when you file your tax return. (Some IRAs, like Roth IRAs, are generally not even entered anywhere on the tax return.) The amount contributed for 2019 is reported by the IRA broker to the IRS after the tax filing deadline. If you wanted to change the year that the contribution is designated under, you would have to get the IRA broker to retroactively change it in their system, and change it in the report they will send to the IRS. If they won't do that, then the alternative is to withdraw the excess amount (including earnings) before the tax filing deadline, to not have a penalty, and re-contribute it for 2020.

Answer (score 0):

Just got some help from TD Ameritrade (the platform I am using to contribute my Roth IRA) specialist.

When I fill the tax return by TurboTax, I can choose to count them in either 2019 or 2020.

But I do need let TD Ameritrade update my info on their platform to count them in 2020 too.

Comment: The last sentence is the most important part of this self-answer. If you told TD Ameritrade that it was a 2019 contribution when you made it, you need to get them to correct their information, or do a withdrawal of the excess contribution for 2019 (and earnings on it also) by 7/15/2020 followed by a new contribution for 2020 (which can wait till after 7/15/2020 to be done; no need to do this when TD Ameritrade will be extra busy taking care of last-minute 2019 stuff).